# Context variable is null in tMysqlInput query

Tags: java, mysql, talend

I have a problem with my job when I want to make a query with 2 context variables. I attached photos with my job and my components and when I run the job, it's giving me this error:

```
Exception in component tMysqlInput_1 (facebook_amazon_us)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mava.facebook_amazon_us_0_1.facebook_amazon_us.tWaitForFile_1Process(facebook_amazon_us.java:2058)
at mava.facebook_amazon_us_0_1.facebook_amazon_us.tMysqlConnection_1Process(facebook_amazon_us.java:798)
at mava.facebook_amazon_us_0_1.facebook_amazon_us.runJobInTOS(facebook_amazon_us.java:5363)
at mava.facebook_amazon_us_0_1.facebook_amazon_us.main(facebook_amazon_us.java:5085)
```

What I want to do in this job: I have a csv file with multiple columns. The first one is called Reporting_Starts. I want to get the first registration from that column and put it in the query for a select like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MONTH(my_table.Reporting_Starts)='"+context.month+"'.
```

I cannot get why my tJava_4 sees the variables and tMysqlInput don't.

In my tJava_4 I have the following code:

```
System.out.println(context.month);[My job][1][after running the job][1][tJava_3][1][tJavaRow_1][1][tMysqlInput_1 query][1]
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information about the job.

Thanks!

Comment: How is your `context.month` variable initialized (context file..etc) ?
And please post the links to your screenshots, I will add them to the post.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13omlsNtFmewk1w0fxiDj6aNgojTNP_f7

Comment: this is the drive where the photos can be found. thank you a lot. Also you can see there where i declare and initialize my variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the iterate links you have, I'm guessing the code isn't executing in the order you expect.  Could you please make the following changes:
Remove all the iterate links from `tFileList_1`
Reorganize your jobs as :

```
tMysqlConnection_1
     |
OnSubjobOk
     |
tWaitForFile_1
     |
  Iterate
     |
tFileList_1 -- Iterate -- tJava_3
                            |
                          OnSubjobOk
                            |
                   tFileInputDelimited_1 -- Main -- tJavaRow_1                                
                            |
                          OnSubjobOk
                            |
                          tMysqlInput -- tMap -- tMysqlOutput (delete mode, set a column as delete key)
                            |
                   tFileInputDelimited -- tMap -- tMysqlOutput (insert csv)
                            |
                          OnSubjobOk
                            |
                        tFileCopy
```

First test with just this part. Then if it works, you can add the rest of your job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working like that. But how can I make the tFileCopy_2 to execute last. I want to move the file after I made the modifications in my database. The scenario is: i read a file from a folder. I extract the first data from the column Reporting_starts from the csv. After that, I select from my database all the rows that have that date. If there are rows selected I'll delete them and then insert the csv. If they don't exist, I directly insert the csv. Just after this job is done, I want to move the file. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer. tFileCopy will be executed after the tFileList has finished with all the files.
Please consider accepting this answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to better suit your requirement; let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I'm happy to help :)